# C function to password match salted sha1

Tags: c, perl, sha1, pam

I am using a perl function to generate passwords in sha1 with a salt.

```
sub  set_new_password{
    my ($newpass)=@_;
    $salt='4Ly5W7xx';
    $pass= encode_base64(sha1($newpass.$salt).$salt);
    return $pass;
}
```

Now I have to verify this password in a C program. 
There are sha1 verifiers like https://pastebin.com/CPC1vYAK but how do I verify passwords with a salt

Is there some sample I can copy from

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!! You clearly have some incorrectly-scoped variables.

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your existing code suffers from a serious security bug. The salt shouldn't be constant. A different, random salt should be used for each password.

```
use Math::Random::Secure::RNG qw( );  # Or some other cryptographic-safe number generator

use feature qw( state );

sub generate_salt {
    state $rng = Math::Random::Secure::RNG->new();
    my $uint32 = $rng->irand();
    return pack('N', $uint32);
}

sub hash_password {
    my ($password, $salt) = @_;
    return sha1($password . $salt);
}

sub encode_password {
    my ($plaintext_password) = @_;
    my $salt = generate_salt();
    my $hashed_password = hash_password($plaintext_password, $salt);
    return join('-',
       encode_base64($salt, ''),
       encode_base64($hashed_password, ''),
    );
}

sub is_correct_password {
   my ($plaintext_password, $encoded_password) = @_;
   my ($salt_base64, $hashed_password_base64) = split(/-/, $encoded_password);
   my $salt = decode_base64($salt_base64);
   my $hashed_password = decode_base64($hashed_password_base64);

   return hash_password($plaintext_password, $salt) eq $hashed_password;
}
```

To change password:

```
my $plaintext_password = '...from user...';
my $encoded_password = encode_password($plaintext_password);
```

To check password:

```
my $plaintext_password = '...from user...';
my $encoded_password = '...from storage...';
if (!is_correct_password($plaintext_password, $encoded_password)) {
   die("Authentication error\n");
}
```

This is still wrong, though. `sha1` is far too weak. `PBKDF2` with at least 10,000 iterations should be used instead.

Comment: 1) Salting prevents pre-building a dictionary. 2) Salting prevents dictionary attacks against multiple users at once (which is the usually way of using a dictionary attack). 3) Salting prevents two people having the same password from having the same encoded password. 4) In the way the password is used, HMAC only helps if you can find a collision for `sha1($plaintext_password)`, i.e. it only helps if sha1 is already broken. HMAC [prevents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Design_principles) other attacks that aren't relevant here.

Comment: There are better options that `sha1`, but HMAC has nothing to do with that.

Comment: See [NIST Digital Identity Guidelines](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf) June 2017. Look at the section about PBKDF2. Excerpts: "Examples of suitable key derivation functions include Password-based Key Derivation Function 2 (PBKDF2", "The key derivation function SHALL use an approved one-way function such as Keyed Hash Message Authentication Code (**HMAC**)", "PBKDF2, the cost factor is an iteration count .... SHOULD be as large as verification server performance will allow, typically at least 10,000 iterations."

Comment: @zaph, Re "*Using SHA1 with a salt is not secure and should not be used for a password verifier.*", I've already conceded that, and that's different then what you originally said.

Comment: @zaph, Re "*Current attacks do not rely on pre-building a dictionary (that is so 80's) but rather fast hash methods such as SHA1 and dictionaries of common passwords.*", Well, which one is it. It doesn't or it does?

Comment: @zaph, Re "*HMAC is just hashing with a salt in a manor that does not allow length extension.*", Like I said, not relevant here.

Comment: "dictionaries of common passwords", not password hashes:   [SecLists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords).

Comment: You created a chat, but then you ignore it? Not only that, but to post some imbicilic straw men?

Comment: @zaph, You're apologizing for the wrong thing; apologizing for following the rules makes no sense, and you're still posting outside the chat.

Comment: @zaph, wut? You don't want to follow the site's rules? You'd rather keep spamming that sha1 shouldn't be used? How nice.

Comment: I've already conceded that three times. Constructive criticism would be better. But hey, you've already wasted all of my time and then some. That's far better!

Comment: Constructive criticism welcome. So far, you've only said "Using SHA1 with a salt is not secure and should not be used for a password verifier.". Not useful.

Comment: @zaph, I promise to look into that. Right now, just going to add that as a one liner. I have no time left.

Comment: Great, I will delete most of my comments.